# copy a table into a new table and add a new column on SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to copy a table into a new table on SQL server 2008. 
Also, add a new column into the new table.

The values of the new column depends on the compare result between the   new table and another table.

Example,

Table1:

```
     col1    col2   col3
     abc    346   6546
     hth     549   974
```

Expected Table1_new:

```
       col1   col2  col3  col4
       abc    346   6546   1
       hth     549   974    0
```

Table2:

```
   col1 
    abc    
    sfsdf
```

If Table2's col1 appear in Table1 col1, mark col4 as 1 in Table1_new, else mark as 0.

The code does not work

```
SELECT *, 
(
      SELECT 1 as col4
       FROM Table2 as a 
       INNER JOIN  Table1 as b
       on b.col1 = a.col1

      SELECT 0 as col4
       FROM Table2 as a 
       INNER JOIN  Table1 as b
       on b.col1 <> a.col1  # I do not know how to do this !!!
)
 INTO table1_new
 FROM table1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you're breaking your database's "normalization" with col4, since it simply expresses information that already exists elsewhere. The problem with that is that the two sources of information can (and believe me, they will) get out of sync. Additionally whenever you modify table2 or table1, you always have to remember to modify the other (or add hard-to-maintain triggers). Unless you have extremely pressing performance issues, I **strongly** recommend against this maintenance disaster waiting to happen. Instead, add it to your queries as you need it. Otherwise, create a view.

Comment: @Alvin Thompson, could you please show an example ? thanks !

Comment: An example (from your data above) is if you later add a row to table2 with the data "hth", but forget to modify table1 in the same transaction. The value for col4 in table1 (for the corresponding row) is now wrong. The value should be 1 according to your rules but it's still 0. All of your apps must now have established rules to deal with this possible inconsistency. Also, if you don't detect the inconsistency until later, it may be difficult to resolve which is correct.

Comment: Since the data in col4 is simply derived from other data, either create a view for it or generate the value for it as needed. That way, it can never be wrong.

Comment: Additionally, since the value of col4 is based on business logic, you're essentially injecting business logic into your schema. This is usually A Bad Idea because business logic can change, and nobody (years down the road) ever remembers all the places where it was used and therefore what needs to be changed. It's best to always try to keep it all in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an outer join:

```
SELECT          table1.col1, col2, col3, 
                CASE WHEN table2.col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS col4
INTO            table1_new
FROM            table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
```

Comment: @ Mureinik  ,  about "CASE table2.col4", it has error: the identifier cannot be found. "table2.col1" also get error.

Comment: @user3448011 arg, stupid typo - it should be `table2.col1` - fixed.

Comment: @user3448011 Seems like I'm having a bad day - dropped the `when` by mistake. Try now.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in several ways.  The following uses an `exists` clause in a `case` statement:

```
insert into table1_new(col1, col2, col3, col4)
    select col1, col2, col3,
           (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1)
                 then 1 else 0
            end)
    from table1 t1;
```

You can also do this with a `left outer join`, but you run the risk of duplicates if `t2` has duplicates.

Comment: @ don Linoff,  I got error of "t1_new" invalid object name.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO T2
  SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3, (COL1+COL2) FROM T1
```

Note that instead of the (COL1+COL2) section you could run other expressions or possibly even a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using `CASE`

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
       WHEN b.col1 = a.col1 THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
   END as col4
FROM Table1 as a 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 as b
    on b.col1 = a.col1
```

EDIT: `Table1` should be the left table as mentioned in @Muerniks answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others already suggested: If you can't solve the problem in one step, try to make smaller steps. E.g. first initialize Table1.col4 with zero:

```
INSERT INTO Table1_new (col1,col2,col3,col4)
SELECT col1,col2,col3,0
FROM Table1
```

After that you will only need to identify the records which have matching partners in Table2 which is a classical inner join:

```
UPDATE t1 SET col4=1
FROM Table1_new t1
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.col1=t1.col1
```